# Is this resistor routed correctly?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

For a friend I'm trying to make a fuzz pedal and found this very flexible fuzz circuit, called "The Fuzz of 1000 Faces," at instructables, credits to Randofo.

However, since it's an old post, I ask the question here (since it's more generic).

Why is the 100 K resistor (in the red circle) used for all transistors under it? Because how I read it, is that it is connected to the collector of the first (2N2222), and then the emitter is connected to all other emitters. But it seems to me, the first is different (why is it not connected to the emitter of the first for example?).

The original circuit can be found here: http://www.home-wrecker.com/multiface.html (thanks jsotola).

It seems to me, if the 2N2222 is not selected (switch is off), there will be no current flowing out of the emitter of 2N2222 so all subsequent transistors will not function, either.

[image]

Because for double checking the complementary comment and answer, I added the following possibilities (changes in Red).

1A Resistor to all emitters:

[image]

1B Resistor to each switch (collectors):

[image]

Comment: the 100 K should be on the output of the first block and the 10 K should be on the output of the second block

Comment: @jjsotola because I just want to double check, you think 1A is what you mean?

Comment: no, look at 1B ... move the 100 K resistor to the right, on other side of the switch ... the 10 K resistor needs to be in a similar place at its associated switch block

Comment: the original circuit uses only two transistors that are each plugged into a socket ... swapping different transistors achieves the desired change in tone quality ... there is a 100 K resistor on the collector of the left transistor and a 10 K resistor on the collector of the right transistor ... your circuit adds a rotary DP6T switch ... it selects the base and collector of a transistor from the group ... the emitters are tied together

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation (it's the same as the answer now :-) ) First I'm going to breadboard it probably (and using the resistors I have ,maybe even more than 6 NPN types). Probably going to use DIP switch boxes instead for the DP6T.

Comment: However, what is the idea behind this weird circuit? I find it interesting from a circuit point of view.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist It is a guitar 'fuzz' effect pedal circuit. He  wants to have a lot of different tone possibiltiies and the switchable components affect the sound. In my case, I want to breadboad it (using the transistors I have) so the guitarist of the band(s) I play in can select the component(s) he likes best.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist,  this is the original, i think .......... using different transistors produces different sounding distortion ... http://www.home-wrecker.com/multiface.html

Comment: @jsotola Yes (didn't see that before, the original). Strange is that here the 100K resistor is between 9V and the collector  (and not as in the answer after the collector).

Comment: @jsotola, Thanks, it looks quite intriguing and a little mystical:)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist actually there are numerous posts about what transistors work best (it seems germanium types are favorite for them).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, i think that you may have been working on this for too long without a break ... the 100 K resistor is connected to the collector in the answer also ... the diagram should have one pair of switches closed, so that one of the transistors is "in circuit"

Comment: @jsotola Yes, well more like 'blind staring' on the same problem. Thanks for the time to explain all details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like the circled 100K resistor & the 10K resistor should be on the moving contact of their respective switches.

Edit: Like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand you well ... I added two examples, I think you are referring to the solution 1B ? Or do you mean that the resistor(s) should be connected at the right side of the respective switches?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, that is how it is supposed to be wired .... perhaps the confusion is caused by the switches ... the left group of transistors is controlled by one DP6T switch ... same for the right group of transistors ... moving the switch connects only 1 of 6 transistors to the circuit

Comment: THanks for this drawing, now it's clear to me (the original drawing was quite confusing to me). I never saw those dashed boxes and they have a 'specific' meaning (thought they were just for grouping some elements, without semantics).

Comment: The original seems to be here: http://www.home-wrecker.com/multiface.html ... but there the resistor is clearly between 9V and the collector, not after it (so I'm afraid it's still not clear for me).

Comment: He plugged the transistors into 3-pin sockets in that arrangement so the switches were not in the equation. The resistor always ends up connected to one collector.

Comment: Thanks again ... yes (stupid of me not to see it).